# GitHub: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I am having some problems working with 
`git clone`.The files are downloaded in my local git folder. Running the command

`git checkout -f HEAD` gives me-

### Error:

> 'The unable to write new index file error caused by the lack of disk space'.

I've manually removed big files from my computer, but still getting the same error.

```
Cloning into 'ffmpeg'...
remote: Counting objects: 7890, done.  
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4412/4412), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (7890/7890), 299.75 MiB | 24.19 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 7890 (delta 3346), reused 7846 (delta 3317)
Resolving deltas: 100% (3346/3346), done.
Checking out files: 100% (7019/7019), done.
fatal: unable to write new index file
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: by default its master I suppose and git checkout -f HEAD do u have a branch called HEAD ?

Comment: Yes. I have a folder called HEAD inside of .git folder. Should I remove that folder?

Comment: no dont delete anything inside .git folder

Comment: once you do a git clone it will create a folder and that folder is your app directory and inside that folder you will have the .git folder. Your app/code folder is not linked to git and using git checkout {branchname} you can checkout to different branches

Comment: Thanks! I put the source code under .git/branches. Is that okay? And do you know how to solve that lack of disk space error?

Comment: What OS you are using ? You can delete some un-necessary files if its in local. If its in server I would suggest to ask someone (server admin to clean up some space)

Comment: Okay. I will ask my server admin to clear up some space!

Comment: @jamie_y, what is under `.git` is *strictly* git's bussiness. You can go sightseeing in there, but only with hands firmly seated in the pockets.

Comment: in my case, a font file contains "?" at the last of the file name.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

When you clone, git gets all the objects from the remote end (compressed and stashed into the `.git` directory). Once it has all the pieces, it proceeds to unpack all files needed to (re)create the working directory. It is this step that fails, due to not having enough space. This might be due to a disk that is full, or a disk quota exceeded (on shared machines, quotas are often enforced to avoid having users grab more than their fair share of space).

Delete your cruft. Make sure you aren't trying to squeeze the Linux kernel or some such monster repository into your few megabytes of account space.

Comment: in my case it was due to long file-name

Comment: @sashikanta check the logs..if it is due to long filenames, then try to take the clone on a small path like C:\checkout\

Comment: if the filename is too long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Answer (score 75):

For me this was due to long file names and doing a simple config as below resolved it

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Comment: nice.. i've been edited  C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig
and inserted longpaths = true in [core] tag.

or.. git config --global core.longpaths true

it's worked to me.  tks

Answer (score 23):

In my case my disk was not full and this is how I solved it:

1. cd into the project directory and un-stage all staged files if any by running `git reset`
2. undo all changes in the working directory by running `git checkout *`

After doing the two steps you should be able to see the project files.

Comment: Right, forgot about that. If the final checkout would overwrite local files, it fails. You can `git stage` them out of the way (for now).

Answer (score 21):

Got the same error when trying to clone a repo from Visual Studio 2017 (v15.6.0).

In my case installing [GIT-LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) locally solved the issue.

Comment: It was the case here as well ... the error message was
...
```git-lfs filter-process: git-lfs: command not found
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/```
...Installing git-lfs resolved the issue

Answer (score 9):

I recently had this problem and the error was that the path of the file where I was cloning the repository was too large, you can do a test by cloning the repository into some folder in C:\

Comment: That's my problem too. "Filename too long" +1

Comment: if the filename is too long: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575662/filename-too-long-in-git-for-windows

Comment: My issue was the file name being too long as well. I had to clone down and shorten the name.

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was due to **colons** in filenames. Once I changed them, everything worked fine.

Comment: same for me , removed colons and no more issue.

Comment: I think mine is caused by a space on the end of the file -- but how do you correct that when you're not the owner of the repo?  error: invalid path 'hapi-fhir-docs/src/main/resources/ca/uhn/hapi/fhir/changelog/5_6_0/2837-search-with-not-modifier-on-multiple-codes.yaml '

Answer (score 9):

In my case I solved this problem by :

1. install git LFS
2. `git config --system core.longpaths true`
3. `git config --global core.protectNTFS false`

resource list:

1. https://git-lfs.github.com/
2. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/error-invalid-path-during-git-clone-to-windows-client-1085186345.html

My drive was not Full

Answer (score 6):

Apart from other possibilities, the major one could be rules imposed by windows on naming files. The git clone and checkout should work fine on linux.

For more info watch this - https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/208

Comment: This was our issue. Filename beginning with a quote. Deleted it on a Linux machine and it was solved.

Comment: I was also facing the same problem, in my case directory name was ending with '.'(dot) which was working fine on Ubuntu/Mac but not on windows...

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

> git config --global core.longpaths true

Answer (score 4):

If you are on windows, you should do:

1. Go to Computer Configuration → Administrative Templates → System → Filesystem in `gpedit.msc` , open `Enable Win32 long paths` and set it to `Enabled`.
2. After that `git config --system core.longpaths true` or edit `gitconfig` (you must run as administrator).
3. Open project directory with `git bash` and run `git reset` after that run `git checkout *`

Comment: Worked!!. The reason for this issue is due to the longpaths.

Comment: On Windows 10, there is no `Enable Win32 long paths` in the path you specified.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. It turns out that my disk was full. You can find out by running

```
quota
```

My result said

```
$ quota

Home Area quota for: jamie_y

Current Usage: 8 GB
Current Limit: 8 GB
```

Run du command to find your disk usage.

```
The du command shows the disk space used by the files and directories in a directory. The -h option makes the output easier to read, and the -s option summarizes the result. For example,

 du -h -s (quoted from http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_dux.htm)
```

Run rm -rf folderName to remove the folder/file.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the git clone folder and run this command

```
git restore --source=HEAD :/
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case only one command fixed the issue.

> **git reset**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because may be your files are too large.
I tried to clone the repository through GitHub Desktop application and it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case - one file name was too long, I used the GitLab website to delete that particular file.

Then cloned again, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, due to the fact that the antivirus of my computer was removing files between download and checkout (Excel with VBA macros in my case). Removing the problematic files from the remote branch solved the issue (or disable the antivirus if you can).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem with git bash. Cloned in Ubuntu terminal instead using HTTP and not SSH and it worked immediately after I authenticated in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, make sure that the file name is not include in the system reserved name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

In my case it was a file named com9 which was causing issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Installing GIT LFS from its website works well for me. Steps are follows:

1. Download relevant binary from the [web](https://git-lfs.com/)
2. From terminal navigate to the downloaded folder by cd (path can be populated by dragging this folder to terminal)
3. Run sudo ./install.sh

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are correct. But if you have "permission denied" issues, they will not work, so you need the following:

```
git clone --config core.longpaths=true repository_url
```

So, you say that you do not set it globally, instead you set it just for this call. And the message will disappear also with permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure Git to ignore the NTFS naming may fix the issue.

```
git config --global core.protectNTFS false
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?