# git clone at windows has been failed

Tags: git

we don't have any problems when we git clone from project on mac and linux distributions and everything work fine but in windows when we git clone from project occurred this error

```
Cloning into 'mango'...
remote: Counting objects: 61211, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (180/180), done.
remote: Total 61211 (delta 92), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (61211/61211), 196.57 MiB | 11.05 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (40317/40317), done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'app/Events/eloquent.created: App': 
Invalid argument
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

and after that project files has been deleted?
my project is under laravel 5.4 framework

My question is why this error occurred in windows and we don't have any problem in other os?

Comment: I believe you have the same problem as this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041752/github-clone-succeeded-but-checkout-failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I clone files with colons in the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991805/how-do-i-clone-files-with-colons-in-the-filename)

Comment: The error looks like you have a colon in the path?

Comment: Windows filenames cannot contain any of these "\ / : * ? " < > |", so you cannot checkout that file because of the colon (:) in the filename. Rename the file or give up cloning that repository in Windows.

Comment: @FBergo yes you are right i delete one file that have this name and work fine thanks bro :)